# Remove double quotation from dict?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, csv

I have a 4.5GB CSV file which I need to remove `"` from. A record currently can look like:

```
47477209,11,HIST,"

CANCELLED",,,,,,,,47140495
```

However it needs to look like this:

```
47477209,11,HIST,CANCELLED,,,,,,,,47140495
```

otherwise when I use it in spark as a `DF` it thinks that it is a new record.

This is what I have currently when reading `CSV` and writing to `JSON`:

```
f = open('changeset.csv', 'rb' )
reader = csv.DictReader(f) 

jsonoutput = 'masterlist2.0.json'
with open(jsonoutput, 'w') as f:
    for x in reader: 
        json.dump(x,f)
        f.write('\n')
```

I was thinking you could do something like this..

```
json.dump(x.replace('"', ''),f)
```

Comment: Doing a straight-up character replace as you suggested will cause all kinds of problems. E.g. It would replace escaped double-quotes as well. Don't do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your problem is not the `"`. Your problem is likely line feeds in the data. Because of these the CSV writer is adding the quotes. You can remove the line feeds, and other surrounding white space from the 4th field with:

```
for x in reader:
    x[3] = x[3].strip()
    json.dump(x, f)
    f.write('\n')
```